# Is it possible to use external data as a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, xml, google-visualization

I am using [Google chart tools](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart).

You can see an example via link. But I want to use external data like csv,xml,txt or excel table as a source to my chart.

```
 function drawRegionsMap() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Popularity'],
      ['Germany', 200],
      ['United States', 300],
      ['Brazil', 400],
      ['Canada', 500],
      ['France', 600],
      ['RU', 700]
    ]);
```

you can see that we give names in the script like 'Germany' or 'Brazil'. 
Is it possible to call these names form external source as I mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will need to load these external sources and convert them to an array. All of this can be done in JavaScript, and you can load the external resources through AJAX. You can learn more about AJAX here: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp), [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Once you have loaded the data from the file into a string in JavaScript you still need to parse it, which depends on the format of your data.